# Can a user have GRANT PERMISSION without having ALL PRIVILEGES?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to create a user who can register other new users, but I don't want him to have `ALL PRIVILEGES`, it looks like I'm doing something wrong here.

I've tried the following

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON database.* TO 'USER' IDENTIFIED BY '123456' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

But when I login with this USER account and try to give privileges to another user MySQL/MariaDB return : `You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT`

Is it possible to have a user who can only select/insert/update on a single database to give those same privileges to new users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. Not just to new accounts, but *any* account that exists.

Based on [the documentation from MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html):

> The optional WITH clause is used to enable a user to grant privileges to other users. The WITH GRANT OPTION clause gives the user the ability to give to other users any privileges the user has at the specified privilege level.
>
> [...]
>
> Be aware that when you grant a user the GRANT OPTION privilege at a particular privilege level, any privileges the user possesses (or may be given in the future) at that level can also be granted by that user to other users.

So, as the documentation notes, an account that has `SELECT`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE` privileges with the option to `GRANT`, can provide those same permissions to other accounts.

However, there are some important details in the documentation to note:

1. Be careful to whom you give the `GRANT OPTION` privilege because two users with different privileges may be able to combine privileges!
2. Suppose that you grant a user the `INSERT` privilege on a database. If you then grant the `SELECT` privilege on the database and specify `WITH GRANT OPTION`, that user can give to other users not only the `SELECT` privilege, but also `INSERT`. If you then grant the `UPDATE` privilege to the user on the database, the user can grant `INSERT`, `SELECT`, and `UPDATE`.

If you are going to allow other accounts to administer privileges, such as a junior DBA or a member of HR, consider reviewing your database permissions auditing process to ensure accidental grants are identified and corrected.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I could not figure out why using the statement `GRANT SELECT, INSERT...`  didn't not work, so I used "HeidiSQL" to customize the permissions and worked like a charm.  And thank you for the explanation about different users combining privileges, I didn't not kew about it.